# What is the meaning of this..."var evt=event||window.event;"

Tags: javascript

What does the following mean in JavaScript?

```
var evt=event||window.event;
```

Comment: Related: [ReferenceError: event is not defined error in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20522887/1048572) and [Why is 'event' variable available even when not passed as a parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33167092/1048572)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It means that the variable `evt` is assigned to the value of `event` or if `event` is undefined it is assigned the value of `window.event`.

How this works is that in javascript, boolean operators don't evaluate to true or false but instead evaluates to the value of the last object that is not falsy* or the falsy value.

So the statement first evaluates the expression `event || window.event`. If `event` is true then the expression does not need to be evaluated any further since an OR only needs one member to be true. Therefore the value of `event` is returned. If `event` is falsy then the the right side of the OR operator needs to be evaluated to determine if the result is false. In which case, if `window.event` is not falsy then its value is returned.

This is a very common idiom to get the event object from event handlers. On standards compliant browsers, the event object is passed as the first parameter to the event handler. But on IE the event object is a global variable. And for historical reasons, all global variables are members of the window object.

So the code should look something like this:

```
element.onclick = function (event) {
  var evt = event ||     // use the value of event if available or
            window.event;// if not assume it's IE and use window.event

  /* ... */
}
```

Note: * falsy values in javascript are: false, 0, null and undefined.

Comment: +1 for ..`historical reasons`: two words to define all the compatibility issues, resuls cross-browser library occurances(like `$`, `Prototype`, 'YUI' etc.) and why the life is then easier and why the life is more complicated.

Answer (score 7):

The code is a hack because Microsoft decided to put their events in the global `window.event` instead of passing it as a parameter to the event function.

So, this code will attempt to set `evt` to the event passed in (which will work for the non-Microsoft browsers) and, if that turns out to be `null` (as it will be for Microsoft browsers), it will then grab it from the global.

From that point on, your function can just use `evt` disregarding browser differences (well, at least those relating to events).

Answer (score 3):

```
var evt=event||window.event;
```

The code above is a shortcut to a IF ELSE statement, and is equivalent to the bellow code:

```
var evt = "nothing valuable yet"; 
if ( event ) {
   evt = event;
} else {
  evt = window.event;
}
```

Two IF ELSE shortcuts in Javascript:

```
var resultIsTrue = true || false; // if first value is true, return first value
var resultIsFalse = true && false; // if first value is true, return second value
```