# Javascript events: window.event vs argument reference (function)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events

**What is the difference between:**

```js
function test (e) {
    console.log("Event: ", e);
}
document.querySelector("button").onclick = test;
```

```html
<button>Click!</button>
```

**and:**

```js
function test () {
    console.log("Event: ", event); // same as window.event
}
document.querySelector("button").onclick = test;
```

```html
<button>Click!</button>
```

They seem to return the exact same object, even containing the same `timeStamp` value in milliseconds.

I often see code using the first example, using `e` or `evt`, but what is wrong with the second example?

I understand that `event` is the same as `window.event`, which is a global variable, but what is the purpose of using `e` if `event` does the same thing?

Comment: event isn't a global property in Firefox, so it will return undefined.

Comment: This will shed some light maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493033/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-var-evt-eventwindow-event

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Standard ways

There are two standard ways to add event listeners: event handlers and `addEventListener`.

### Event handlers

Initially DOM0 (not defined by any spec but widely implemented), they are properly defined in the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handlers).

> Many objects can have **event handlers** specified. These act as
>   non-capture event listeners for the object on which they are
>   specified. [[DOM]](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/references.html#refsDOM)
>
> An [event handler](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handlers) has a name, which always starts with "`on`" and
>   is followed by the name of the event for which it is intended.
>
> An [event handler](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handlers) can either have the value null, or be set to a
>   callback object, or be set to an [internal raw uncompiled handler](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#internal-raw-uncompiled-handler).
>   The [`EventHandler`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#eventhandler) callback function type describes how this is
>   exposed to scripts. Initially, event handlers must be set to null.
>
> Event handlers are exposed in one of two ways.
>
> The first way, common to all event handlers, is as an [event handler
>   IDL attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handler-idl-attributes).
>
> The second way is as an [event handler content attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handler-content-attributes).

#### Event handler IDL attributes

> An **event handler IDL attribute** is an IDL attribute for a specific
>   [event handler](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handlers). The name of the IDL attribute is the same as the
>   name of the [event handler](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handlers).

The event handler will be the function assigned to the IDL attribute. That function (or callback) will be called with the event as its only argument:

> [Invoke](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#concept-invoke-event-handler) *callback* with one argument, the value of which is the
>   [`Event`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#event) object *E*

Example:

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function(evt) {
  console.log('Event: ' + evt);
};
```

```html
<button>Click!</button>
```

#### Event handler content attributes

> An **event handler content attribute** is a content attribute for a
>   specific [event handler](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handlers). The name of the content attribute is the
>   same as the name of the [event handler](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handlers).

When you set them, the handler will be an [internal raw uncompiled handler](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#internal-raw-uncompiled-handler). That means that [getting the current value of the event handler](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#getting-the-current-value-of-the-event-handler) will be more complex: the string will be parsed as the `FunctionBody` of a function which has an argument named `event`:

> Let the function have a single argument called `event`.

Examples:

```html
<button onclick="console.log('Event: ' + event);">Click!</button>
```

```js
document.querySelector("button").setAttribute('onclick',
  "console.log('Event: ' + event);"
);
```

```html
<button>Click!</button>
```

### addEventListener

It was introduced by [DOM L2 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget-addEventListener), and now [DOM4](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-eventtarget-addeventlistener) defines it as:

> The `addEventListener(type, callback, capture)` method must run these
>   steps:
>
> 1. If *callback* is null, terminate these steps.
> 2. Append an [event listener](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event-listener) to the associated list of [event listeners](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event-listener) with **type** set to *type*, **callback** set to
>      *callback*, and **capture** set to *capture*, unless there already is an [event listener](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event-listener) in that list with the same **type**,
>      **callback**, and **capture**.

When the event listeners are [invoked](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event-listener-invoke), the callback is called with the event as its only argument:

> Call *listener*'s **callback**'s `handleEvent`, with the event passed
>   to this algorithm as the first argument

Example:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  console.log('Event: ' + evt);
});
```

```html
<button>Click!</button>
```

---

## Compatibility notes

Old IE didn't support `addEventListener`, and didn't pass any argument to event handlers.

However, it provided another way to access the event: `window` objects inherit an `event` property from `Window.prototype`. That property has a getter which returns the event object.

Therefore, a common way to support old IE is using an argument and overriding it with `window.event` if necessary:

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function(evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;
  console.log('Event: ' + evt);
};
```

```html
<button>Click!</button>
```

New IE passes the event as an argument in both `addEventListener` and event handlers, so that is no longer necessary. It also continues implementing `Window.prototype.event`.

Similarly, Chrome implements `window.event`, probably to support old code written for IE.

However, better avoid using that:

- It is not standard.
- The standard alternatives are widely implemented (except on old IE).
- It doesn't work on all browsers, for example on Firefox.

Comment: Wow, very informative, thanks. I was using chrome and their fallback confused me. If it doesn't work in Firefox that's a cause for concern. Curious: Could using `event` as the argument name instead of `evt` cause any issues or conflicts? I find it easier to read.

Comment: @bryc You can name it like you want, like `e`, `evt`, `event`, `foobar`, ... It only must be a valid [identifier](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6).