# Why does this form validation appear to bypass `event.preventDefault();`?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation

I am trying to write a simple form with some basic validation, but the pressing the submit button bypasses `event.preventDefault();` and the form gets submitted anyway.

```js
function myFunction() {
  if(document.getElementById("username").val() == ''){
    alert('Please enter a username');
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

This is the code for the form, the username input field, and the submit button:

```html
<form method ="POST" action="db/registerinsert.php" class="content formregister" id="registerform">
  <div class="content formcontact">
    <section class="section">
      <div class="columns">
        <div class="column is-8 is-offset-2">
          <div class="field">
            <label class="label">Username</label>
            <div class="control has-icons-right">
              <input class="input" name="username" id= "username" type="text" placeholder="" required="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field is-grouped">
            <div class="control">
              <button class="button is-link" type="submit" onclick="javascript:myFunction()" Value="Submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</form>
```

I also have `required=""` on the `<input>` field but leaving the field empty doesn’t trigger this either.

Comment: I'm still getting the alert with either .val or .value and then it moves onto the insert page? And i dont appear to be getting any errors. really strange.

Comment: I am getting the alert. But it still continues onto the insert page. Fixed the .value as you mentioned and changed to an addEventListener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few tiny mistakes. The important ones are:

- Incorrectly retrieving the `<input>` value
- Not listening for the `submit` event

But using obsolete features like the global `event` or using `onclick` attributes will also lead to trouble, eventually.

### The `<input>` value

`<input>` elements don’t have a `val` method. Don’t confuse [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/val/) with [the native DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#properties). jQuery uses the `val` method, whereas the native DOM API uses the `value` property.

Your function will throw `Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...).val is not a function` on invocation.

The value you want to compare is either one of these:

```js
document.getElementById("username").value // Native DOM; let’s stick with this one
document.querySelector("#username").value // Native DOM
$("#username").val() // jQuery
```

You can also append a `.trim()` to any of them if you want to disallow whitespace-only inputs, too.

### The comparison

`==` and `!=` are almost [never recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/4642212). They’re not always intuitively transitive since they oftentimes unnecessarily perform type coercion. Use `===` and `!==` instead.

The `if` condition therefore should look like this:

```js
if(document.getElementById("username").value === ""){ /* … */ } // Native DOM
```

### The event object

The way you’ve used `event.preventDefault();` uses the obsolete global [`window.event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event). [It’s not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29423624/4642212). Use the [`event` argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback) instead. See [What exactly is the parameter e (event) and why pass it to JavaScript functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35936365/4642212).

### The proper event type and event target

Clicking the submit button is only *one* way of submitting a form. You could press <kbd>Enter</kbd> as well. Think about it: what is it that you want to prevent? You want to prevent form submission. So listen for the [`submit` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) instead. You’d do this on the `<form>`, not the `<button>`. Only `<form>` events dispatch `submit` events.

### Naming conventions

Not crucial, but to avoid confusion in the last step, I’m going to rename `id="registerform"` to `id="registerForm"`, since [JavaScript uses camelCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Guidelines/Code_guidelines/JavaScript#variable_naming) in several places.

### Binding the event and bringing everything together

Inline event handlers like `onclick` or `onsubmit` are [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) or jQuery’s [`.on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

This is the event binding, using native DOM APIs. It also uses [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```js
document.getElementById("registerForm").addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  if(document.getElementById("username").value === ""){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Please enter a user name.");
  }
});
```

Using jQuery:

```js
$("#registerForm").on("submit", (event) => {
  if($("#username").val() === ""){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Please enter a user name.");
  }
});
```

In the HTML, remove `onclick` completely. You’ve also thrown in a [`javascript:` label](https://stackoverflow.com/q/372159/4642212) for some reason…

Finally, `<button>`s don’t really use a `value` attribute. Their tag content is already sort of their value.

```html
<form id="registerForm" class="content formregister" method="POST" action="db/registerinsert.php">
  <!-- Omitting stylistic containers -->
  <input id="username" name="username" class="input" type="text" required="required">
  <button class="button is-link" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

---

### Alternative: `reportValidity` and `checkValidity`

You’ve included a `required` attribute. The way to make use of this is to call [`reportValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) or [`checkValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/checkValidity) on the form. Note that these methods don’t have full browser support yet, as of 2021.

```js
document.getElementById("registerForm").addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  if(!event.target.reportValidity()){
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Using `reportValidity`, the browser UI will already display a message like “Please fill out this field” if it’s empty. The similar method `checkValidity` will also work the same way in the JS, but won’t show the user a message, so your custom `alert` can be reintroduced.

See the MDN articles on [form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation) and [constraint validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation) for more, e.g. setting [`pattern`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern).

---

### Alternative: `requestSubmit`

There’s a new API, called [`requestSubmit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit) which simplifies form validation, but isn’t well supported as of 2021. This relies on the `required` attribute.

```js
document.querySelector("registerForm button[type='submit']")
  .addEventListener("click", ({target}) => target.form.requestSubmit(target));
```

```html
<form id="registerForm" class="content formregister" method="POST" action="db/registerinsert.php">
  <!-- Omitting stylistic containers -->
  <input id="username" name="username" class="input" type="text" required="required">
  <button class="button is-link" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The JS above also uses [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [the `form` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLButtonElement#properties).

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this is what you want but if you want to cancel the submit action you should pass the event as a parameter to the function like this:

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', myFunction);

`function myFunction(e) {
   if(document.querySelector(".input").value == ''){
      alert('Please enter a username');
      e.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

Hope it Helps

Comment: Yes, but this will not work if the `onclick` attribute is used. And please fix the `val` error, too.

Comment: `innerHTML` is always empty for `<input>`s. It’s `value`.

Comment: I meant the form, sorry

Comment: Okay, two of the three mentioned mistakes have been fixed. Only removal of `onclick` is missing…

Comment: That was the point, an alternative for the click event