# How to execute a JS code block on pressing ESC key?

Tags: javascript, keycode, event-listener

I want to execute a JS code when user presses <kbd>ESC</kbd> key. Please help me how can I do this? My current code is not working. I don't know where I'm doing wrong? I'm just a beginner so please help me out..

```js
function hideModalKeyPress(e)
{
 if(e.keyCode == 27)
 {
  document.getElementsByClassName('modalOverlay')[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
 }
}
```

```css
.modalOverlay
{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: black;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="modalOverlay" onkeydown="hideModalKeyPress(e);">Press ESC to hide me.</div>

/*
 * I want to set the div's visibility to hidden
 * when user presses ESC key
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery and do the following:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) {
      $(".modalOverlay").css('visibility', 'hidden');
  }   
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x0gLy4yb/1/)

Or in pure JavaScript:

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
        document.getElementById("modal").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
};
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x0gLy4yb/8/)

Comment: can you provide a pure JS format version of this? It will be helpful.

Comment: Added pure JS as well :) Keep in mind that you need to set the div's ID to `modal`.

Comment: can you explain a little how the above code works??

Actually I didn't understand the 2nd line - evt = evt || window.event;

Comment: You can find a good explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493033/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-var-evt-eventwindow-event :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", hideModalKeyPress, false);
function hideModalKeyPress(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 27)
    {
        document.getElementsByClassName('modalOverlay')[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

Here is the working jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/7jrfrz26/