# Why is 'event' variable available even when not passed as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder why does the following code work in some browsers? I.e. even when there's no parameter to a `click()` function however `event` variable exists and `dosomething` method is called on the event trigger object?

```
$(<selector>).click(function () {
  $(event.target).<dosomething>
});
```

Comment: _global_ `event`. Try `event` in console

Comment: that doesn't explain why does it work only in certain browsers/versions

Comment: @SergeyPauk: It's a Microsoftism.

Comment: @Amadan works in chrome as well

Comment: @SergeyPauk: Lots of Microsoftisms work in Chrome. In fact, lots of standards came from IE; simply because Microsoft never listened to anyone and developed new things they wanted, leaving others to adopt them or risk users' pages not working in the minority browsers, jeopardising their market share even further.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Why is 'event' variable available even when not passed as a parameter?

In a word: History. Before this stuff was standarized, Microsoft used a *global* `event` variable the browser set before calling the event handler. The DOM2 standard defined it as an argument to the handler instead. For years, the Microsoft-specific global was non-standard and in fact didn't work in Firefox. When Chrome came along, they decided to throw a bone to Microsoft-specific code that used the global so they supported both. Ultimately, the global was standardized as a legacy API for compatibility reasons ([spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-window-event) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event)) and Firefox added it in v63 (behind a flag) and unflagged in v66+.

Even on the browsers where that code works, note that `event` will be a raw event object, not the jQuery-enhanced one. That means that, for instance, on IE8 you can't call `event.preventDefault` because IE8 doesn't supply that function. jQuery would if you accepted the argument, because jQuery provides an event object with standardized features even on browsers that are missing those features.

Comment: Thanks for the Info :), didn't knew this